# Sticky menu issue with responsive web design

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've been battling an issue I cannot seem to solve.
Please refer to this test page: http://lucid-build.com/test/

What I'm trying to accomplish is when the page is resized 979px and below, the header switches to the mobile version and then the location of where the nav stickies should adjust to the top of the logo area, like it is stretched past 980px.

below is my script:

```
function resizeBanner() {
    var bannerH = $(".banner img").height();
    $(".banner").css("height", bannerH);
}

if($(window).width() <= 979) {
    alert("mobile");
    function fixedNav() {
        var logoT = $(".logo img").offset().top;
        var bannerH = $(".banner img").height();

        $(window).resize(function() {
            $(".banner img").height();
        });

        $(window).scroll(function() {
            if($(window).scrollTop() > logoT ) {
                $("#header").addClass("fixed").css(("height"),159);
                $(".banner").css(("margin-top"),-bannerH+159);
                $("body").css(("margin-top"),bannerH+22);
            } else {
                $("#header").removeClass("fixed").css(("height"),("auto"));
                $(".banner").css(("margin-top"),0);
                $("body").css(("margin-top"),0);
            }
        });
    } 
} else {
    alert("desktop");
    function fixedNav() {
        var logoT = $(".logo img").offset().top;
        var bannerH = $(".banner img").height();

        $(window).resize(function() {
            $(".banner img").height();
        });

        $(window).scroll(function() {
            if($(window).scrollTop() > logoT ) {
                $("#header").addClass("fixed").css(("height"),120);
                $(".banner").css(("margin-top"),-bannerH+120);
                $("body").css(("margin-top"),bannerH+18);
            } else {
                $("#header").removeClass("fixed").css(("height"),("auto"));
                $(".banner").css(("margin-top"),0);
                $("body").css(("margin-top"),0);
            }
        });
    }
};

$(window).resize(function() {
    resizeBanner();
});

$(window).load(function() {
    resizeBanner();
    fixedNav();
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("body").hide();
    $("body").fadeIn("slow");

    resizeBanner();
});
```

You might also notice it starts doing all sorts of weird things on scroll when resize 979px and below. :(

Thank you!

Comment: You might want to look into CSS media queries.

Comment: Media Queries were designed for exactly this. Browsers calculate CSS much faster than JS.